# ViewGroup vs FrameLayout, loading images inside of them

Tags: android, layout

I have this situation. I'm creating custom GridView. I have a ScrollView and I use `MyViewGroup` inside of it, `MyViewGroup` extends `ViewGroup`. I want to load images. For each image I use a cell, which is  `RelativeLayout` and has ImageView in it. Like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Problem is that cells are being loaded correctly, but images are not being loaded. BUT if I extend `MyViewGroup` from `FrameLayout` instead of `ViewGroup` it works correctly. But I have to use `ViewGroup` and not `FrameLayout` I override only `OnLayout` for `MyViewGroup`.

So my question is how can I make images to load correctly using `ViewGroup`, what property or properties does `FrameLayout` has, that doesn't have `ViewGroup`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Another important part for a view is the measurement part done in the `onMeasure` method.